# How can I GRANT PRIVILEGES on a VIEW to a user?

Tags: mysql

I am trying to give VIEW privileges with the next code.

GRANT SELECT ON database.view TO 'login'@'%';

But mysql workbench tells me the next:
table 'tables.priv' is marked as crashed and should be repaired.

I was just expecting to give privileges on this VIEW and I have looked for how to grant VIEW privileges and have found nothing about a different code.

Could someone please tell how to grant privileges on a VIEW?

Comment: Uhm… repair the table first?

Comment: It is not a table but a VIEW

Comment: You said you ran it on `database.view` not `tables.priv`.